# how to find a particular node in Neo4j

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

how to find the particular node using the Neo4j API.When i refereed the docs i got some code to get all nodes However if i have a node called "XYZ" I would like to know how to obtain ONLY that particular node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [Indexing Service](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Indexing_with_IndexService) which will allow you to index your nodes with key-value pairs. Once you've indexed your nodes you can query the graph and retrieve nodes which match a given key-value.

Comment: The above link didn't work for me, thought I'd share this link http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html (it's a starting point...)

Answer (score 0):

If your node type is a FirstName and its ID is "XYZ" you can do it with:

```
MATCH(n:FirstName {ID: 'XYZ'}) return n
```

this will return all the nodes with ID = "XYZ"